# Is this the most elegant way to ascertain whether site is running locally?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to improve my skills here. For various reasons (including db connection, debugging output etc etc) I need to determine if my sites are running locally (XAMPP) or remotely. At the moment I do this... *which does work*:

```
$root    = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$baseurl = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$parts   = explode("/",$root);
$base    = $parts[0];

if($base == "C:") {
 if(!defined('LOCAL')){
  define('LOCAL', true);
} else {
 if(!defined('LOCAL')){
  define('LOCAL', false);
};
```

...but I cannot help feeling there's a more elegant solution to detect local versus remote?

Bear in mind the local domain is never simply "localhost" - I have hundreds of local sites all using their own domains mapped in XAMPP's vhosts.

Thanks very much for your suggestions.

Comment: You could set up a `<VirtualHost>` in Apache on your local server; in that set an environment variable like `LOCAL` - then just check whether that's been defined or not. You don't need to do any code changes between your local and online versions then.

Comment: I can set an environment variable right in the `<Virtualhost>` ?! That's VERY interesting!

Comment: Yeah - Apache mod_env : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html ... you can even do it through mod_rewrite; which you need to do if you want to use that environment variable *in* a rewrite since mod_rewrite runs before mod_env.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flat-PHP, I would use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`.  With XAMPP, by default, `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is `::1`.

If you're coding on the same machine that runs XAMPP, you can also compare `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: Those variables output "127.0.0.1" so that's a great suggestion to cut a few lines of my code, thanks very much :)

Comment: @mayersdesign `::1` is for IPv6 , `127.0.0.1` should be for IPv4 so check if it's either of those 2 since they mean the same address in practice.

Comment: @apokryfos - Yes I see, and learned something else (well something haha) about IPv6 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Can't help but feel that your current solution would break if you deployed to a remote windows server. That's definitely not good practice. Laravel in particular uses [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to solve this by deploying an environment configuration file on each server and defining basic constants that will be used.

For example you can have a `.env` in your local:

```
APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=local
```

and remotely

```
APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=notlocal
```

Then you can do on startup:

```
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

Then you can use [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) to get the value:

```
if(!defined('LOCAL')){
  define('LOCAL', getenv("APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT") == "local");
};
```

Comment: I should have indicated that I am Linux servers only, but it's great feedback for Windows, users, upvoted.

Comment: Pretty much the same principle I'd use but I'd just set the environment variable directly in the `<VirtualHost>` rather than an environment config file.

Comment: @CD001 Not sure if there's any advantages or disadvantages for this approach compared to apache config. I prefer this one because I do use Laravel (which already comes with this out of the box). VirtualHost is probably easier if you're not using any framework.

Comment: Doesn't make a huge amount of difference I don't think - just that with it being set in `<VirtualHost>` you can't inadvertently overwrite the online config file with the local one if you run a bulk upload. I tend to actually have a load of config files (local.cfg.php, server1.cfg.php) and set the path to load the relevant config in the `<VirtualHost>` - but yeah, I've never used Laravel.